# SwiftUI iOS - Focus on TextField and SecureField only works after second or third tap

Tags: ios, swiftui

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine


struct LoginTwo: View {
    
    @State var errorInvalidMail: Bool = false
    @State var errorSixCharsPass: Bool = false
    
    @State var inputEmail: String = "joooo@blaaaaaaa.de"
    @State var password: String = ""
    
    var body: some View{

        ZStack{

            ScrollView{
                VStack{

                    VStack(alignment: .leading){

                        TextField("Email", text: $inputEmail)
                            .padding()
                            .keyboardType(.emailAddress)
                            .disableAutocorrection(true)
                            .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
                            .background(Color("InputFieldBG"))
                            .cornerRadius(5.0)
                            .accentColor(Color("ClickableLink"))
                            .onChange(of: inputEmail) { inputEmail in
                                errorInvalidMail = false
                             }



                        SecureField("pass", text: $password)
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color("InputFieldBG"))
                            .cornerRadius(5.0)
                            .accentColor(Color("ClickableLink"))
                            .padding(.top, 6)
                            .onChange(of: password) { password in
                                errorSixCharsPass = false
                             }


                    }
                    .padding()

                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("")
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true) // hides the "back" or previous view
        .background(Color("AccentColor"))

    }
}
```

As said in the title, it takes at least two taps till the fields are focused, what could be the problem?

The issue is on iPhone 8. It instantly works on emulator, but tapping on other stuff like back buttons also works instantly on the iPhone 8 so it doesn't look like hardware issue

Comment: Can you include a [mre]?